# Simple mysql insert into error, query not executing and data not inserting into table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have some insert code like the following:

```
$a = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

$query = "INSERT INTO users(email, password, first_name, last_name, active, registration_date, city) VALUES ('$e', SHA('$p'), '$fn', '$ln', '$a', NOW(), '$c')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Sorry an error happened");
```

and it's not inserting in to the database. The connect code is:

```
DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'admin');
DEFINE ('DBPW', 'asd123');
DEFINE ('DBHOST', '127.0.0.1');
DEFINE ('DBNAME', 'test');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPW, DBNAME);
```

I think it has something to do with the SHA or the NOW() commands, it used to work with mysql, but changing it to mysqli is proving differcult.

I've tried adding ".$variable." parentheses to the variables but no luck there.

Comment: Remove the `@` in `@mysqli_connect`, you could be suppressing important errors.

Comment: What if you try it without the SHA?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't show anything different though, still getting "sorry an error happened".

Comment: Trying it without the SHA didn't change anything.

Comment: If you see your trigger message, then fetch the SQL error, i.e. `echo(mysqli_error($dbc))`

Comment: I tried "$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or mysqli_error($dbc);" and it returned nothing.

Comment: what is your error message ?

Comment: field "username" doesn't have a default value. I've fixed the problem in the database and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For other users: The problem I had was that the database didn't have NULL values for the fields I was trying to insert into. So to fix this, go to your mysql PHPadmin, login and go to your database, click on structure, and in the column called `default` ensure that you have NULL set to all of the fields. For example: if most say NULL but there's one that says `none`, the insert into will not work. So tick the tickbox on that field (the field that says "none" under the default column) and click "change". In there you can set the field default to NULL using the drop down list.

I had this problem when migrating the code from `mysql` to `mysqli`. mysql seemed to insert into without regards to the "NULL requirement". Easy fix though.